# Is there a way to skip a unit test suite in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have some unit test that should not be run, as of now, is there a way I can skip them? Other than using fdescribe on the ones I want to run.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you're looking to skip tests, it's 'x' in front of describe() or it():

```
xdescribe('some test', () => { });
```

And maybe just skip a test in a block:

```
describe('some other test', () => {
  xit('skip this test', () => { });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the entire test suite during run time based on some condition, you can do something like:

```
(yourCondition ? xdescribe : describe)('My Test Suite', function () {
...
})
```